# nodejs resize and save image from remote server

Tags: node.js, image-processing, image-resizing, save-image, sharp

node js resize and save image from remote server.

Hi,
How can I resize image without to save locally and then to save it.
when I run bellow code, I get error: "Error: Input buffer contains unsupported image format"
code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var sharp = require('sharp');

function getImage()
{
request('https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png', function (err, res, body) {

var binary = Buffer.from(body.toString(), 'base64');   

sharp(binary).resize(198, 110).toFile('test.jpg', (err, info ) => 
  { 
      console.log('err: ', err);
      console.log('info: ', info);

  });      
});
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found resolving for my question:

```
var resizer = sharp().resize(198, 110).toFile('test.jpg', (err, info) => { 
    console.log('err: ', err);
    console.log('info: ', info);
  });    
  request('https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png').pipe(resizer);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can make sure that `https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png` returns the image, you can try to pipe the response directly to sharp rather than converting response to base64 format & processing.

```
var resize = sharp(binary).resize(198, 110);
resize.on('error', function() {
  //handle error
});
resize.on('finish', function() {
  // done
});
request('https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png')
.pipe(process);
```

Update:

Removed `.toFile('test.jpg');` part

Comment: thanks for your answer, I resolve my problem, code:   var resizer = sharp().resize(198, 110).toFile('test.jpg', (err, info) => { 
    console.log('err: ', err);
    console.log('info: ', info);
  });    
  request('https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png').pipe(resizer);

Comment: @MichaelFedorov, Remove `.toFile('test.jpg', (err, info) => { console.log('err: ', err); console.log('info: ', info); })`. That is not necessary, if you are only going to use pipe.